# Linearity of the adjoint transformation of a bilinear map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, bilinear-form

> **2.3. Definition**
>   If $(V,b)$ is a bilinear space, then
>   $$
>          \hat{b}
>   \colon V
>   \to    V^*
> $$
>   defined by
>   $$
>     (\hat{b} x)(y)
>   = b(x,y)
> $$
>   is a obviously a linear transformation.
>   $\hat{b}$ is called the *adjoint* transformation.
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySsQe.png)

I want to show that $\hat{b}$ is linear map so take element $x, z$,
so
$$
    \hat{b}(x+z)y
  = b(x+z,y)
  = b(x,y) + b(y,z)
$$
and similarly
$$
    \hat{b}(cx)y
  = b(cx,y)
  = cb(x,y) \,.
$$
Is it correct or not? Please help regarding this.
I also want to know one example regarding adjoint transformation of bilinear form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is linear.

The standard example is the bilinear form on $\Bbb R^n$:
$$b(x, y) =\langle x, y\rangle=x_1y_1+\dots+x_ny_n$$
In particular, for the $i$th basis vector $e_i$, we get $\hat be_i=y\mapsto y_i\ (\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R) $ is the $i$th coordinate map. 
And for $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)^T=x_1e_1+\dots+x_ne_n$ we get
$$\hat bx=x_1\hat be_1+\dots+x_n\hat be_n$$
Note also that for a finite dimensional vector space $V$, if $b$ is a nondegenerate synmetric bilinear form (meaning $\forall y:b(x, y) =0\, \implies x=0$), then $\hat b$ is an *isomorphism* between $V$ and $V^*=\{f:V\to\Bbb R\mid f\ \text{linear} \} $.

Comment: can you please give some non trivial example for this? Trace is one of the example I guess. But I can't formalize it.

Comment: You mean the trace form on matrices $(A, B) \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(AB)$?

Comment: Yes does it have adjoint transformation structure?